# Playing two sounds in sequence with SoundPool

Tags: android, r.java-file, soundpool

Actually, I want to play all the sounds in raw folder in sequence. When I click the button only the first one is played. I will be grateful for your help . This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SoundPool soundPool;
private int sound1, sound2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(2)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();
    } else {
        soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    sound1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.a, 1);
    sound2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.d, 1);

}
public void playSound(View v) {
    soundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    soundPool.play(sound2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    soundPool.release();
    soundPool = null;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play a sound simultaneously using SoundPool for a specific period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509608/how-to-play-a-sound-simultaneously-using-soundpool-for-a-specific-period-of-time)

Comment: @emandt sequence are simultaneous have different meanings. So it's not a duplicate of it

Comment: I want the second sound will be played after the first one finished

Comment: How about declaring a new int variable, " int allSounds==sound1 + sound2;" and then " soundPool.play(allSounds, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);"?

Answer (score 0):

I used Howard Liu's [SoundPoolPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35931413/5172715) class, a wrapper around the `SoundPool` that calculates the duration of the audio file playing (using the `MediaPlayer`) and calls the custom `OnCompletionListener` event after the playback is finished using `postDelayed`.

In the handling of the `OnCompletionListener` event, you just need to start playing the next audio file.